# printing random array variable only once in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment for uni where I have to create a Java program that produces a random pairing customers and their transaction totals.

It comes in two parts where the first part produces the customers and their transactions like so:

```
Customer ID, Transaction Value
1, 74.36 
1, 44.98 
3, 6.44
0, 19.13
3, 59.44
2, 81.56
0, 87.21
4, 40.9
1, 42.11
3, 66.05
```

the second summarises the total number of transactions for each customer like so:

```
Customer: 1 Transactions: 3.0
Customer: 1 Transactions: 3.0
Customer: 3 Transactions: 3.0
Customer: 0 Transactions: 2.0
Customer: 3 Transactions: 3.0
Customer: 2 Transactions: 1.0
Customer: 0 Transactions: 2.0
Customer: 4 Transactions: 1.0
Customer: 1 Transactions: 3.0
Customer: 3 Transactions: 3.0
```

My problem is the second section should only produce each customer ID once i.e `1,3,0,2,4`. I can only do this using int and double variables and without creating any other arrays or structures. My code can be found below.

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class Assignment3 {
   public static long studentNumber=1234567; 

   public static int customerID[];
   public static double transactionValue[];

   public static void initialiseData(int size) {
     customerID = new int[size];
     transactionValue = new double[size];

     Random rand = new Random(studentNumber);
     for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
       customerID[i] = rand.nextInt(size / 2);
       transactionValue[i] = rand.nextInt(10000) / 100.0;
     }
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
     int size=10;

    initialiseData(size);

    // Your code should only be below this line
    double transaction = 0;
    int customer = 0;
    int customer_Total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int customer_count = 0;
    double transaction_Total = 0;

    System.out.println("Customer ID, Transaction Value");

    for (size= 0; size < customerID.length; size++) {
    customer= customerID[size];
    transaction= transactionValue[size];
    System.out.println(customer + ", " + transaction);

    }

    System.out.println("");

    for(customer_count = 0; customer_count < customerID.length; customer_count++) {
      transaction_Total= 0;
      customer_Total = customerID[customer_count];
      count = customerID[customer_count];
      //System.out.println(count);

      for (int customer_count2 = 0;
           customer_count2 < customerID.length;
           customer_count2++) {                         
        if (customer_Total == customerID[customer_count2]) {
          transaction_Total++;

          //System.out.println(customer_count2);
        }
      }

      System.out.println("Customer: "+ customer_Total + " " +
                         "Transactions: " + transaction_Total); 
    }

    // Your code should not be below this line

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: in this code:

```
for(customer_count = 0; customer_count < customerID.length; customer_count++) {
  transaction_Total= 0;
  customer_Total = customerID[customer_count];
  count = customerID[customer_count];
  //System.out.println(count);

  for (int customer_count2 = 0;
       customer_count2 < customerID.length;
       customer_count2++) {                         
    if (customer_Total == customerID[customer_count2]) {
      transaction_Total++;

      //System.out.println(customer_count2);
    }
  }

  System.out.println("Customer: "+ customer_Total + " " +
                     "Transactions: " + transaction_Total); 
}
```

add the following after 'transaction_Total= 0;':

```
int wasBefore = 0; //are you allowed to use boolean variables?
for (int customer_count3 = 0;
       customer_count3 < customer_count;
       customer_count3++) {                         
    if (customer_Total == customerID[customer_count3]) {
      wasBefore = 1;
    }
}
if (wasBefore==1) {continue;}
```

In this way you still get random order of customers without repreating them

Comment: Then in your solution add one more loop to find whether this particulkar customer_id exists on a position before customerID[customer_count], and if so, 'continue' the loop with next customer_count value

Comment: unfortunately the customer ID's cant be sorted. They have to remain like this 
Customer: 1, Transactions: 3 
Customer: 3, Transactions: 3 
Customer: 0, Transactions: 2 
Customer: 2, Transactions: 1 
Customer: 4, Transactions: 1

Comment: Thanks for you're help but i cant use boolean variables only int and double

Comment: OK sorry i didn't see your comment just after you edited your first post so i have it working correctly. Thank you for your help! It's so obvious as well, i have been staring at the code so much i got stuck!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at how [Collections.shuffle](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html) works.  In your case you can create an array of all possible values and "shuffle" then in a random order.

Comment: i cant use anything but ints and doubles so no extra arrays

Comment: You can't even use the two arrays in your code, I am confused.

Comment: the arrays were given to me and i then have to process the information stored in them only using int and double variables. I can't create any arrays aside from the ones given to me. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. So I would put in the customer ids you want to have, into the array you and shuffle them so they are in a random order.  They will be random but unique (or occur any specific number you want)

Comment: True, but its very simple and you can do the same thing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

so your homework is a little bit irritating, since it is unusual to make such a restriction as don't use arrays.

But you could do the following:
Your customer ids go from 0 to size/2 so it is possible to write a loop  which counts the transactions for every possible customer.
Like this

```
for(int customer_id = 0; customer_id <= size /2 ; customer_id++){
    int transaction_sum = 0;
    for (j= 0; j < customerID.length; j++)
        if(customerID[j] == i)
             transaction_sum++;
    if( transaction_sum > 0)
        System.out.println("Customer: " + customer_id +
                           "  Transactions: " + transaction_sum);
}
```

but this is not a nice solution, beacuse this is slow for large number of possible ids.

Comment: thanks for the comment. when i ran this it produced Customer: 0  Transactions: 2
Customer: 1  Transactions: 2
Customer: 2  Transactions: 2
Customer: 3  Transactions: 2
Customer: 4  Transactions: 2

Comment: unfortunately its not the answer im looking for. Its ridiculously annoying

Comment: Customer: 1, Transactions: 3 
Customer: 3, Transactions: 3 
Customer: 0, Transactions: 2 
Customer: 2, Transactions: 1 
Customer: 4, Transactions: 1